# How to close chromium print screen in puppeteer?

Tags: printing, chromium, puppeteer

Does anyone know how to close the print screen which is similar to clicking (File->Print in google chrome) in Puppeteer?

I am trying to close the print screen which is initiated by a page.click() in puppeteer.

Comment: Are you using it with headless: false ?

Comment: Yes, I am using headless: false so I can help debug

Comment: it's same as how you handle popups in a browser, it's mentioned in the puppeteer docs - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-dialog